# How to make photo collage in canvas image using Fabric JS?

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I am using Fabric JS for the customizing products. Ii that case, I want to make photo collage image uploading functionality using Fabric JS in canvas. I don't have any idea about it.

Below is the image that I really want for a collage making. Please anyone tell me how to make it using Fabric JS or sample code to do this.

Please follow this image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try multiple canvas to create photo collage image. On each canvas anyone can add image(s). Final result will produce as photo collage.
    Use multiple canvas as follows,

```
$(XML).find('view').each(function() {
    var canvasXMLCnt = 0;
    var viewType = $(this).find('view_type').text();
    var divID = 'dynamicDiv_'+viewType;
    createDynamicDiv(divID);
    var aLink = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="view_'+viewType+'"> View '+viewType+' </a>';
    $("#multipleViewsDiv").append(aLink);
    $(this).find('canvas').each(function() {
        canvasXMLCnt++;
        var canvasID = $(this).find('canvas_id').text();
        var variable_DynamicCanvas = 'canvas_'+viewType+'_'+canvasXMLCnt;
        var dynamicCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        dynamicCanvas.id = variable_DynamicCanvas;
        dynamicCanvas.className = 'dynamic-canvases';
        var createdDiv = document.getElementById(divID);
        createdDiv.appendChild(dynamicCanvas);
        canvasArray.push(variable_DynamicCanvas);
    });
});
```

Check this [reference](https://jsfiddle.net/mullainathan/bax7ydbb/)

Comment: Is it possible to add it inside png image

Comment: Actually im using dynamic image inside that image (phonecase) i want collage

Comment: Definitely, we can add dynamic images inside canvas by using fabricjs image adding function.

Comment: My image is in canvas i can append multiple canvas inside that canvas?

Comment: No, You can't merge multiple canvas(s). But, you can multiple canvas(s) as per reference.

Comment: i got error of Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null @Mullainathan

Comment: No problem i have solved this issue actually i tried to get div before dom content loading